# How can we know if the request is from App embedded browser(Safari webview) or Actual Safari Browser?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, browser, safari, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm facing this issue with `Rails` app.

Actually Embedded Safari don't allow to access mobile Camera or Mic, while Actual Safari do.

So I just want to justify that in request.

I have used `gem 'browser'` but it's returning all parameters same for both mode.

If there is anything else which can detect that difference?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If your app requires those features you should use [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) instead of browser sniffing which is deeply flawed.

Comment: Thanks, moving on feature detection, but still I think browser should also show the user agent as different for webview and native with some keyword to identify it.

Comment: One of the reasons browser sniffing is so flawed is that user agent string is not a very reliable way to determine the browser or the capabilities.

Comment: Agree with you.